# Possible to programmatically pullout of a simple WAIT situation?

Tags: java, multithreading

My question is about if its possible in `Java` to know if a thread is going to wait for a lock and pullout that thread ( itself ) immediately if that is the case i.e. if thread is going to wait for a lock.

e.g. for below theoretical code,

```
public void f() { 
  synchronized(this) { 
   //long tasks 
  }
}
```

If `Thread-A` is already in long running `synchronized` block, `Thread-B` comes in , `lock` is not immediately available  so decides to pullout ( or waits for x seconds then pulls out ) and to try again.

I guess its not possible with primitive locking via `synchronized` block but just wish to know ideas for - if a thread is unwilling to go to `WAIT` state or if possible to forcibly pull out a thread from `WAIT` state.

I mean, is it possible to write something in `Thread-B` OR `Thread-A`code for this logic?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `Object.wait(long timeout)`. The thread will quit waiting after the specified period or whenever it's notified (via `Object.notify()`).
So the long-running thread could call `notify()` before it's done to signal the waiting thread to continue (and not wait until the timeout expires).

To kick out a thread from within another, you can call `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread holding the lock (assuming that `InterruptedException` is not ignored in that thread); this approach is a bit extreme and I don't think it's the way to go here.

This is all done using "primitive" synchronization tools. You can achieve the same (and more) using `java.util.concurrent.Lock`s and `Condition`s.

Comment: This doesn’t make the slightest sense. To invoke `wait` on an object, a thread must hold the lock of that object, which the thread won’t get until the other thread releases it. So the thread still is blocked *before* it has a chance to invoke `wait` and once it has the lock, there is no point in waiting for the lock it already has.

Comment: @Holger: The underlying assumption here was that `wait()` would be called *first* (i.e. before the "long tasks" will start running), so the lock was available and was immediately released by the waiting thread. But I do understand your concern: my feeling was that the OP needed a bit of clarification on how to use the primitive synchronization tools; and apparently, I was right: my answer got accepted against all odds. :)

Comment: Well, the question was about checking the availability of a lock (or whatever actual achievement) *without* waiting. While a wait operation with a short timeout could fulfill that role, it’s not a solution, if it is a one-time use assuming that the thread will start waiting *before* the other started the operation but can never again do this check, once the other thread has started. There’s no way around stating that the long running thread must not hold the lock during the entire operation, if the intrinsic lock of `synchronized` is used.

Comment: @Holger: I totally agree with what you're saying. However, we may have read the OP question differently. My understanding was that the OP was trying to get sense of inter-thread communication tools. Specifically, `wait(long timeout)` does seem like the proper answer for `"decides to pullout ( or waits for x seconds then pulls out )"`...`"I guess its not possible with primitive locking via synchronized block but just wish to know ideas."`

Comment: @Holger: The other answers both provide the "correct" `tryLock` solution, and yet they seem to have missed the point. As a side note, I was about to delete my answer when it got accepted; so this kind of confirms that my intuition was right. Since my out-of-tune answer is the accepted one, maybe the question needs editing and probably it will end up closed "as duplicate". What do you think ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible using primitives from `java.util.concurrent` package. I.e. you can use `ReentrantLock` which basically emulates standard `synchronized` block, but also have `tryLock` method with timeout as well.

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public void f() {
    try {
        if (lock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            try {
              //you have the lock here...

            } finally {
                //unlock
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            //pull-out
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use optimistic semantics using [`Lock objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). Something like [`tryLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28%29):

> Acquires the lock only if it is free at the time of invocation.
>
> Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately with the value true. If the lock is not available then this method will return immediately with the value false.

Example from the docs:

```
  Lock lock = ...;
  if (lock.tryLock()) {
      try {
          // manipulate protected state
      } finally {
          lock.unlock();
      }
  } else {
      // perform alternative actions
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not possible if I don't wish to change code of `f()` ?

Comment: I don't know how. Maybe someone else will be more helpful. It seems futile though, given that synchronized is a statement and not a function.